# Render List out of Order

Tags: react-native

So I have a SectionList, which I initially display objects like

```
var data =[a, b, c, d]
this.setState({
  Data: data
});
```

I then call a function which reorders my data. i do this by reording the data as

```
var NewDataOrder = [d,c,b,a];
this.setState({
  Data: NewDataOrder
});
```

Keeping the same data objects, but just reordering. Upon doing this, the order the flatlist renders will change briefly, but then just go back to showing a,b,c,d (When it should be showing d, c, b ,a).

My guess is this must be an efficiency thing with flatlist/virtualized list, where it knows it already rendered that object, and puts it in its original position.

Is there a way I can force a new order?

Comment: can you please share you flatlist code ?

Comment: There can be lots of things to cause a re-render. Please add [mcve] to your question.